# JavaScript - Improve my grid search algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

I have made my own "GhettoSearch," which is used to find the closest path between 2 given coordinates over a Grid, AKA a "list of coordinates."

The grid is an array like this:

`var grid [ [somedata, [x,y,z], somedata], [somedata, [x,y,z], somedata] ]`etc..

My start and stop positions is only coordinates, the Z coordinate is irrelevant at the moment.

I can almost get to the end, but some detoures are made because of my cost function.

Here is how the search looks complete: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jenMg.png

Here is the code I currently use for the search:

```
var Main = {
    GhettoSearch: function(Start, Stop, Grid){
    var Pgreed = 1; //From current position to next nearby nodes
    var Tgreed = 0.25; //from current position to target node

    var Pcost = 0;
    var Tcost = 0;

    var open = [];
    var closed = [];
    var aReturn = [];

    for (i = 0; i < Grid.length; i++) {
        Worldmap.GetNode("Node_" + Grid[i][0]).style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

        Pcost = Heuristics.Distance.Manhattan(Grid[i][1], Start, Pgreed);
        Tcost = Heuristics.Distance.Manhattan(Grid[i][1], Stop, Tgreed);

        open.push([i, (Pcost + Tcost)]);
    }

    do {
        var TmpData = [0, Infinity];
        var TmpForI = null;

        for (i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {
            if (open[i][1] < TmpData[1]) {
                TmpData[0] = open[i][0];
                TmpData[1] = open[i][1];
                TmpForI = i;
            }
        }

        closed.push(TmpData);
        open.splice(TmpForI, 1);

        for (i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {
            Start = Grid[TmpData[0]][1]; //is now the start for recently closed node

            Pcost = Heuristics.Distance.Manhattan(Grid[open[i][0]][1], Start, Pgreed);
            Tcost = Heuristics.Distance.Manhattan(Grid[open[i][0]][1], Stop, Tgreed);

            open[i] = [open[i][0], (Pcost + Tcost)];
        }

    } while (open.length > 0);

    var PathID = null;
    var TmpDist = Infinity;


    for (i = 0; i < closed.length; i++) {
        var NodeID = Grid[closed[i][0]][0];
        var NodeCoords = Grid[closed[i][0]][1];
        var NodeCost = closed[i][1];

        aReturn.push([NodeID, NodeCoords, NodeCost]);


        //var Dist = Heuristics.Distance.Manhattan(NodeCoords, Stop, 1);
        if (NodeCost < TmpDist) {
            TmpDist = NodeCost;
            PathID = i;//Because you will remove the closest cord elese. OR? will u xD
        }

    }

    aReturn.splice(PathID, closed.length);



    return aReturn;
    }
};
```

As you can see on the image, while going upwards it goes back and fills the empty spots besides the straight path up, how can I avoid this?

Yes, I have looked at different search aproaches such as BFS and a star, but I have problems implementing this in my own search function

Comment: Drawing step numbers in the cells (or using different colors) may help you to debug this (= to see how exactly this goes wrong). Your code does not seem to include  Heuristics.Distance.Manhatten? BTW: Have recently implemented Dijkstra for arrays, maybe it's useful here in some way: https://jsfiddle.net/stefanhaustein/orpenu8s/62/

Comment: Everything goes to hell when there is a "shorter" path on the way to the goal since its "shorter",Heuristics.Distance.Manhatten is only the manhattan distance
http://jsfiddle.net/ntu3yxpz/, i will take a look at your code aswell

Comment: Consider moving this question to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: hmm, how do i move it? cant really find it in the edit section, do i have to post it there and remove it here?

Comment: Why do you need the manhattan distance function at all? If you don't look at diagonal neighbors and only all direct horizontal and vertical neighbors are connected, shouldn't that imply manhattan distance?